# how to change a bool value in prestashop 1.6 back end by icon click

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to change my printing status ,I am able to place the icon to change the status but the change is not occurring when I click the Print status icon shown in the image I have placed the callback as changePrintStatus

the code is reaching  initProcess() when the change status icon is clicked,But after that what exactly must happen ??Or do i need to call any other function/override function ? (I want to do the same as in customers list where we change active status of customers ,similarly I  want to do here for my custom module)

[image]

```
<?php

    require_once(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.'eticketprinting/eticketprinting.php');
    require_once(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.'eticketprinting/classes/Eticket.php');

    class EticketController extends ModuleAdminController
    {
            public $module;
            public $html;
            public $tabName = 'renderForm';

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->tab = 'eticket';
            $this->module = new eticketprinting();
                 $this->addRowAction('edit');
            //$this->addRowAction('edit');
          //  $this->addRowAction('view'); // to display the view 
            //$this->addRowAction('delete');
            $this->explicitSelect = false;
            $this->context = Context::getContext();
            $this->id_lang = $this->context->language->id;
            $this->lang = false;
            $this->ajax = 1;
            $this->path = _MODULE_DIR_.'eticketprinting';
            $this->default_form_language = $this->context->language->id;
            $this->table = _DB_KITS_PREFIX_.'print_eticket';
            $this->className = 'Eticket';
            $this->identifier = 'id_print_eticket';
            $this->allow_export = true;
            $this->_select = '
            id_print_eticket,
            ticket_id,
            ticket_no,
            product_id,
            print_status,
            date_add,
            date_upd
            ';
            $this->name = 'EticketController';
            $this->bootstrap = true;
            $this->initTabModuleList();
            $this->initToolbar();
            $this->initPageHeaderToolbar();
           // $this->initFieldList();

            //$this->initContent();
            parent::__construct();
            $this->fields_list = 
            array(
            'id_print_eticket' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('E-Ticket Print ID'),
            'width' => 25,
            'type' => 'text',
            ),
            'ticket_id' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Ticket- ID'),
            'width' => 140,
            'type' => 'text',
            ),
            'ticket_no' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Ticket No'),
            'width' => 140,
            'type' => 'text',
            ),
            'product_id' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Product ID'),
            'width' => 100,
            'type' => 'text',       
            ),
            'print_status' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Print Status'),
            'align' => 'center',
            'type' => 'bool',
            'callback' => 'changePrintStatus',              
            'orderby' => false,     
            ),
            'date_add' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Date Add'),
            'width' => 140,
            'type' => 'text',
            ),
            'date_upd' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Date Update'),
            'width' => 140,
            'type' => 'text',
            ),
        );

        }

       public function changePrintStatus($value, $eticket)
        {
        return '<a class="list-action-enable '.($value ? 'action-enabled' : 'action-disabled').'" href="index.php?'.htmlspecialchars('tab=Eticket&id_print_eticket='
        .(int)$eticket['id_print_eticket'].'&changePrintVal&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('Eticket')).'">
        '.($value ? '<i class="icon-check"></i>' : '<i class="icon-remove"></i>').
        '</a>';
        }


        public function initProcess()
        {
        parent::initProcess();
        //d($this->id_object);
        if (Tools::isSubmit('changePrintVal') && $this->id_object) {
                if ($this->tabAccess['edit'] === '1') {
                    //d("reached here");
                    $this->action = 'change_print_val';
                } else {
                    $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('You do not have permission to change this.');
                }

            }
        }

        public function postProcess()
        {
            //When generate pdf  button is clicked 
        if (Tools::isSubmit('submitAddeticket')) {
                if (!Validate::isDate(Tools::getValue('date_from'))) {
                    $this->errors[] = $this->l('Invalid "From" date');
                }

                if (!Validate::isDate(Tools::getValue('date_to'))) {
                    $this->errors[] = $this->l('Invalid "To" date');
                }
                if (!Validate::isInt(Tools::getValue('id_product')) || Tools::getValue('id_product')=='' ) {
                    $this->errors[] = $this->l('Invalid Product/select a product ');
                }

                if (!count($this->errors)) {
                    if (count(Ticket::getByProductNDateInterval(Tools::getValue('id_product'),Tools::getValue('date_from'), Tools::getValue('date_to')))) {

                        //d($this->context->link->getAdminLink('AdminPdf'));
     Tools::redirectAdmin($this->context->link->getAdminLink('AdminPdf').'&submitAction=generateEticketPDF&id_product='.urlencode(Tools::getValue('id_product')).'&date_from='.urlencode(Tools::getValue('date_from')).'&date_to='.urlencode(Tools::getValue('date_to')));
                    }

                    $this->errors[] = $this->l('No tickets has been found or Ticket Generated Already for this period for Product ID:'.Tools::getValue('id_product').' (Change the Print Status generate the E-Ticket Again)');
                }
            } else {
                parent::postProcess();
            }

        } 










    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was  missing the process function :

**But note that $this->action = 'change_print_val';
 and  name f the process  must be similar in my case processChangePrintVal

So if action is $this->action = 'change_printStatus_val'; then process name must be processChangePrintStatusVal**

I added Below function

```
/**
* Toggle the Eticket Print Status flag- Here the update action occurs
*/
public function processChangePrintVal()
{
$eticket = new Eticket($this->id_object);
if (!Validate::isLoadedObject($eticket)) {
$this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('An error occurred while updating Eticket Print Status information.');
}
$eticket->print_status = $eticket->print_status ? 0 : 1;
if (!$eticket->update()) {
$this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('An error occurred while Eticket Print Status customer information.');
}
Tools::redirectAdmin(self::$currentIndex.'&token='.$this->token);
}
```